# Find all pairs of intersecting rectangles with linq

Tags: c#, linq, rectangles

I have a list of Rectangles (xpos, ypos, widht, height):

```
List<Rectangle> rects = new List<Rectangle>();
```

This method can tell if two rectangles intersect: 
[Rectangle.IntersectsWith()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith(v=vs.110).aspx)

I want to get all the pairs of intersecting rectangles from the list using linq... is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!

```
var intersecting = rects
    .SelectMany((x, i) => rects.Skip(i + 1), Tuple.Create)
    .Where(x => x.Item1.IntersectsWith(x.Item2))
    .ToList();
```

Note though that this is an O(n^2) operation without some form of acceleration (e.g. keeping a list of the `Rectangle`s for each the x and y dimensions, sorted, so that you can do a single O(n) pass in each dimension).

Personally, I'd just stick to the typical nested loop for clarity:

```
var intersecting = new List<Tuple<Rectangle, Rectangle>>();
for (int i = 0; i != rects.Count; ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j != rects.Count; ++j) {
        if (rects[i].IntersectsWith(rects[j]))
            intersecting.Add(Tuple.Create(rects[i], rects[j]));
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome, is there a way to exclude pairs of the same rectangle? (x intersecting x) ?

Comment: Hmm, whoops, yeah hang on :-)

Comment: The `Skip` increases the computational complexity to O^3, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Cameron's answer works for small numbers of rectangles. If you run into performance issues with larger numbers, you may add some space-partitioning strategy to reduce the number of intersection candidates to check, using a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).